# I am unable to understand how to code a logic for money splitting among group of people using MEAN

Tags: javascript, logic, mean-stack

I am working on a project named "Splitter", where I need to create a group and split the money among N number of people in short similar to splitwise app but I am confused at the logic part, where every individual can update the amount and get the overall amount an individual gets or owes others.

Please let me know if you need more clarification on my question. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-code would be:

```
amount_every_person_owes = total_spent / number_of_people
for person in group:
    amount_this_person_owes = amount_every_person_owes - amount_this_person_spent
```

Of course, after arriving at the amount each person owes, you'll have to create a mapping as to who owes how much to the other. I'll leave that part to you.